# Usar Attach con claves compuestas en Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Estoy intentando actualizar un registro en una tabla y para ello utilizo Entity Framework, para obtener el registro que voy a modificar utilizo `Find` y la clave, que en este caso es una clave compuesta por dos campos, mi duda es si hay alguna manera de realizar la actualización mediante Attach con claves compuestas, les muestro el código de cómo estoy realizando la actualización en este momento:

```
using (REPLICAEntities context = new REPLICAEntities())
            {
                Lectura lec = context.Lecturas.Find(Fecha, NuTanque);

                //en esta parte actualizo los datos del registro



                context.SaveChanges();
            }
```

Lo que quiero es usar `Attach` en vez de `Find`

De antemano muchas gracias por su ayuda.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Muchas gracias Leandro por tu respuesta, pero siempre si utilicé `Attach()` para actualizar el registro, lo hice de una forma similar a la siguiente:

```
using (REPLICAEntities context = new REPLICAEntities())
            {
                context.Lecturas.Attach(new Lectura { Fecha = DateTime.Now.Date, NuTanque = 2 });

                lectura.Lectura1 = 12345;

                context.SaveChanges();
            }
```

Adjuntando el objeto `Lectura` y llenando los campos que son la clave compuesta y posteriormente modificando solo el campo que necesitaba actualizar.

Answer (score 0):

Si la clave compuesta esta mapeada y tienes la instancia de la entidad con datos asignados a esas propiedades que forman la clave compuesta deberias poder hacerlo sin problema

[Working with entity states](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/saving/change-tracking/entity-state)

algo como esto

```
Lectura lec = new Leactura(){
    Fecha = Fecha,
    NuTanque = NuTanque,
    //otras propiedades
};

using (REPLICAEntities context = new REPLICAEntities())
{
    context.Entry(lec).State = EntityState.Modified;

    context.SaveChanges();
}
```

En lugar de usar el `Attach()` usas el `Entry()` para poer definirle el estado indicando que aplique un `update`

Comment: Que tal Leandro, ¿con `Entry()` tengo que colocar todos los campos de la tabla o solo es necesario colocar los campos que quiero que se actualicen?

Comment: Tienes que asignar valor a todos las propiedades, ya que estas creando una entidad nueva la cual marcas para update, realizara un update de todos los campos, no tiene forma de determinar cuales cambiaste. Cuando usas el Find() la entidad tiene tracking por lo tanto las propiedades que modificas se marcan como dirty entonces sabe que solo debe realizar el update unicamente de estas. Quizas cambia si haces un Entry() y luego cambias el valor a la propiedad ya que estara dentro del sistema de tacking y podras conocer lo que cambiaste marando esa propiedade como dirty.